# How to parse a message from a text file with c# that spans multiple lines?

Tags: c#

Given this log file, how can I read a line with multiple new lines (`\n`) with a `StreamReader`?
The `ReadLine` method literally returns each line, but a message may span more that one line.

[image: Larger Image for the down votes]

Here is what I have so far

```
using (var sr = new StreamReader(filePath))
using (var store = new DocumentStore {ConnectionStringName = "RavenDB"}.Initialize())
{
    IndexCreation.CreateIndexes(typeof(Logs_Search).Assembly, store);

    using (var bulkInsert = store.BulkInsert())
    {
        const char columnDelimeter = '|';
        const string quote = @"~";
        string line;

        while ((line = sr.ReadLine()) != null)
        {
            batch++;
            List<string> columns = null;
            try
            {
                columns = line.Split(columnDelimeter)
                                .Select(item => item.Replace(quote, string.Empty))
                                .ToList();

                if (columns.Count != 5)
                {
                    batch--;
                    Log.Error(string.Join(",", columns.ToArray()));
                    continue;
                }

                bulkInsert.Store(LogParser.Log.FromStringList(columns));

                /* Give some feedback */
                if (batch % 100000 == 0)
                {
                    Log.Debug("batch: {0}", batch);
                }

                /* Use sparingly */
                if (ThrottleEnabled && batch % ThrottleBatchSize == 0)
                {
                    Thread.Sleep(ThrottleThreadWait);
                }
            }
            catch (FormatException)
            {
                if (columns != null) Log.Error(string.Join(",", columns.ToArray()));
            }
            catch (Exception exception)
            {
                Log.Error(exception);
            }
        }
    }                   
}
```

And the Model

```
public class Log
{
    public string Component { get; set; }
    public string DateTime { get; set; }
    public string Logger { get; set; }
    public string Level { get; set; }
    public string ThreadId { get; set; }
    public string Message { get; set; }
    public string Terms { get; set; }

    public static Log FromStringList(List<string> row)
    {
        Log log = new Log();

        /*log.Component = row[0] == string.Empty ? null : row[0];*/
        log.DateTime = row[0] == string.Empty ? null : row[0].ToLower();
        log.Logger = row[1] == string.Empty ? null : row[1].ToLower();
        log.Level = row[2] == string.Empty ? null : row[2].ToLower();
        log.ThreadId = row[3] == string.Empty ? null : row[3].ToLower();
        log.Message = row[4] == string.Empty ? null : row[4].ToLower();

        return log;
    }
}
```

Comment: I forgot to post my code.. sorry.

Comment: My eyes! Fix the image before downvotes come in

Comment: How are the messages separated? with a period? Just need the pattern to distinguish a message and then decide if a Regex would be more appropriate.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I would use [Regex.Split](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.text.regularexpressions.regex.split.aspx) and break the file up on anything that matches the date pattern (ex. `2013-06-19`) at the beginning of each error.

Comment: I was think something along those lines myself.

Comment: Seems like the best option

Comment: This should work: `\d{4}-\d{2}-\d{2} \d{2}:\d{2}:\d{2}.\d{4}`

Comment: Working example: http://regexpal.com/?flags=g&regex=%5Cd%7B4%7D-%5Cd%7B2%7D-%5Cd%7B2%7D%20%5Cd%7B2%7D%3A%5Cd%7B2%7D%3A%5Cd%7B2%7D.%5Cd%7B4%7D&input=blah%202013-06-19%2000%3A00%3A09.1815%20blah

Comment: Ha, I had just started doing my own .. ([0-9]{4})-([0-1][0-9])-([0-3][0-9])\s([0-1][0-9]|[2][0-3]):([0-5][0-9]):([0-5][0-9]).([0-9][0-9][0-9][0-9])

Comment: Heh, yeah you can replace any instance of `[0-9]` with `\d`.  Makes it a little more concise.

Comment: I used yours and the it works..but now that I can see what split did to the text, I'm losing the date portion of the logging statement, which is crucial to this implementation ... shoot!

Comment: Hrrm, based on the documentation, if you are using .NET 2.0 or later it should be including the matches as well as the split elements in the returned array.  If it's not I would create a new question, post your code and see if someone see's what it missing.

Comment: It's called capturing parentheses, and it sort of works, but each date is a separate element in the array.. I think this is as close as I'm going to get.. I'm going for it

Answer (score 2):

If you can read the entire file into memory (i.e. `File.ReadAllText`), then you can treat it as a single string and use regular expressions to split on the date, or some such.

A more general solution that takes less memory would be to read the file line-by-line. Append lines to a buffer until you get the next line that starts with the desired value (in your case, a date/time stamp). Then process that buffer. For example:

```
StringBuilder buffer = new StringBuilder();
foreach (var line in File.ReadLines(logfileName))
{
    if (line.StartsWith("2013-06-19"))
    {
        if (sb.Length > 0)
        {
            ProcessMessage(sb.ToString());
            sb.Clear();
        }
        sb.AppendLine(line);
    }
}
// be sure to process the last message
if (sb.Length > 0)
{
    ProcessMessage(sb.ToString());
}
```

Answer (score 0):

It is hard to see your file. But I would say read it line by line and Append to some variable.
Check for end of message. When you see it, do whatever you want to do with the message in that variable (insert into DB etc...) and then keep reading the next message.

```
Pseudo code

read the line
variable a = a +  new line
if end of message
    insert into DB
    reset the variable
continue reading the message.....
```